# How do static and dynamic create a singularity?

Tags: c#, computer-science

In [the C# programming language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765) Chris Sells states:

> I begin to wonder about any language where the following string 
>   of characters is both valid and meaningful:

```
class Foo
{
    public static dynamic DoFoo()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

> Of course this means that the DoFoo method is a type method (as
>   opposed to an instance method) and that the type of the return value
>   is unknown until runtime, but it's hard not to read DoFoo as both
>   static and dynamic at the same time and worry about an occurrence of a
>   singularity.

I believe Chris means something like..."we don't want to produce a language that implies that a method belongs to a type and the type could be anything"...but I can't find any evidence of this nor of the impact of such a design.

I found [Technological singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity), but that appears unrelated.  What does Chris mean by a "singularity" in this case?  Why are singularities troublesome?

Comment: I voted to close because I believe this will find a more receptive audience at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in this case, Chris is assuming an alternative meaning of the word static that would imply that it is the diametric opposite of dynamic.

This oxymoron-ic method signature might encourage the appearance of a black-hole or other unexpected physical phenomenon.

Comment: ...but most likely won't.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that the combination of two opposite notions, "static" and "dynamic" sounds confusing there and even a little bit funny. Although there both notions concern DIFFERENT things and in fact CAN be combined, usually in computer science static and dynamic are opposites.

I think then that this was supposed to be a joke then, by allowing a language to combine opposite notions you create a language that owns anything (as it owns a contradition) which he calls "singularity".

Answer (score 2):

I think the author is just being cheeky here.

It seems he is alluding to a [Gravitational singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity), or in other words, seeing a method that is both one thing and that thing's opposite at the same time can make one worry that using it will cause the Earth to be swallowed up into a black hole.